# I would like to buy a SSD but before, I want to know something

Tags: linux, windows, hard-drive, ssd

So I would like to have a SSD and I would like to know if you can store the data of your programs on a HDD. So my SSD would be used just to run the OS mainly. Would it be worth getting a SSD and using it this way? Most SSD cost a lot and for a cheaper one you will have less space. I would have both Windows and Linux on each one and one HDD that has something like 2TB of space. Is there something better I could do?

Comment: See other answers. However, it is useful to keep some of your data on the SSD (internet cache, for instance). Personally I use the HDD for only bulky things (photos, music, videos...). With Linux this is quite transparent if you use soft links are the right places.

Answer (score 2):

SSD for system and HDD for data is fair compromise between price and performance.

- On ***Windows***, there is an elegant way how to achieve this, with detailed description in [How to move **Users** folder to another location](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/1964-move-users-folder-location-windows-10-a.html).
- The process is much easier on ***Linux*** as you can usually specify **Home** directory mount point during installation.

---

I did this even on HDD only systems in the past as separation of system and user files helped with prevention of fragmentation.

Comment: My setup is like this too.  I have my OS on the SSD, and my music, pictures, and other files on the HDD.  Also this setup lets me back up my OS by making an image of the SSD and writing it directly to the HDD.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible.

Connect the SSD install windows that is your C: drive.
Any other drives you install with have a different drive letter like d:,e:,f:

Simple save or install whatever you want on the C: drive and everything else on a different drive.

As far as windows is concern its all just storage.

Depending on your exact needs, you could install virtual box, and virtualize the linux OS.  The primary disadvantage is you won't be able to use your GPU to its fullest ability.  Basically you won't be gaming in a  virtualized OS.
If you want to have multiple OS you have to partition the hard drive so each OS has its own sandboxed area.

**The space you assign to linux will not be available in windows**

However, linux can mount and interact with the files on a windows system.